# How to add extra data to a table widget in Pyside6

Tags: datagridview, widget, tags, pyside6

I am trying to add a separate data structure to each table widget in my stacked tree widget list. When I access the selected table widget, I want this information to be available to the code managing the stacked widget.

I am primarily a C# developer, so basically I'm looking at something like the .tag attribute of a Data Grid View.

I have been searching google for some time and it doesn't seem possible.  I'm looking into a parallel list of data structures corresponding to each entry in the stacked list, but don't know how to determine the data structure list index from the selected tree widget

Comment: QObjects are represented by standard python objects, so you could just create attributes as you'd do with anything else. Eg: `self.tableWidget.someValue = xyz`. If you want a more Qt compliant way, use QObject [dynamic properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#dynamic-properties). If you need to pair custom data for *each* item in the table, use [`QTableWidgetItem.setData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidgetitem.html#setData) with custom roles. If you need further help, please improve your question and clarify what you actually want to do and its purpose.

Comment: @musicamonte - Thanks.  Make this an answer and I'll choose it. I forgot about the nature of python objects in this respect.  I'm a C# guy, and you don't do it that way

Comment: Can you please clarify if you want to set custom data for the whole table or associate data to individual cells?

Comment: Just to the table widget itself, not a row or column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PySide (just like PyQt) is a binding that exposes Qt objects by wrapping them into Python objects. In Python, "everything is an object", which can also be read as "everything is an `object` instance".

When a Qt object is made available to Python, it actually is an instance of a `object` subclass that "wraps" the Qt object by providing an interface to its members, including its functions.

Except for basic protected types, any Python object can have any arbitrary attribute which can be set and accessible through the dot notation, so the solution is quite simple: just create the attribute.

```py
self.myTableWidget = QTableWidget()
self.myTableWidget.someValue = 'hello'
```

It's important to keep two aspects in mind, though.

First of all, one should always be very careful about creating such attributes: as a rule of thumb (valid for Python in general, not just Qt bindings), custom members should not overwrite existing ones if they have different behavior or purpose, because they may be necessary in other places within the code or, more importantly, they can be *virtual* functions that are internally called by Qt and, as such, should respect the expected behavior (including function arguments and returned values). It's good habit to always check the official Qt API documentation for the class at hand until you're experienced enough: just check the "List of all members, including inherited members" link near the top of every documentation page.

Then, Qt has its own way of setting and accessing *properties* (see the [Qt property system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html)) which, in some cases, may be preferable to pure Python attributes which are completely invisible to Qt, since they are actually part of the *Python wrapper*, not the Qt object. One typical case is the `objectName` property, which can be used as a selector type in QSS (similarly to the `id` attribute of CSS) or to search for child widgets using `findChild()`.